# js redirect functions of one class to another

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one class in JS (`class1`) which receives the `class2` in the constructor.

Now, what I want to achieve is that I want to be able to call all the functions of `class2` on the `class1`, but I don't want to write all the function declarations in `class1` and then each one of them calling on `class2`.

Is there any clean way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a Proxy:

```js
class Worker {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
    method1() {
        console.log(this.name, 'method1')
    }
    method2() {
        console.log(this.name, 'method2')
    }
}


class Facade {
    constructor(worker) {
        this.worker = worker
        return new Proxy({}, this)
    }
    get(target, prop) {
        return prop in this.worker ? this.worker[prop] : this[prop]
    }
    ownMethod() {
        console.log('facade own method')
    }
}

let f = new Facade(new Worker('worker1'))

f.method1()
f.method2()

f.ownMethod()
```

Another one is to copy method references to the facade object:

```js
class Worker {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
    method1() {
        console.log(this.name, 'method1')
    }
    method2() {
        console.log(this.name, 'method2')
    }
}


class Facade {
    constructor(worker) {
        this.worker = worker
        for (let func of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(worker.constructor.prototype))
            this[func] = worker.constructor.prototype[func].bind(worker)
    }

    ownMethod() {
        console.log('facade own method')
    }
}

let f = new Facade(new Worker('me'))

f.method1()
f.method2()

f.ownMethod()
```

In Typescript you can use `f = ... as (Facade & Worker)` [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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), but there might be better solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @georg.. BTW, is there any way that typescript also recognizes these copied functions ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: updated with a playground link, but you might want to ask a new question about TS specifically, because I'm by no means an expert.